# Making insecure images sources secure client-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl

I let users on my VanillaForums forum choose whether or not to use the `https` protocol and I want to test if I can change image sources on the client's side using jQuery.

I want this code to change the protocol in the image source links to `//` instead of `http://` and load before the images have loaded, so I used `.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.protocol == "https:") {     
        var $imgs = $("img");
        $imgs.each(function () {
            var img_src = $(this).prop("src");
            if (img_src.indexOf("http://") < 0) return;
            var new_img_src = img_src.replace("http:", "");
            $(this).prop("src", new_img_src);
        });
    }
});
```

While it does work in changing the image sources, the URL bar still shows this:

[image]

And the console gives a warning that `http://someimageurl...` is not secure.

Do I need to move the code to the top of the page or will that not make a difference?

Comment: Does it start loading images before `ready` fires? You can do the replacement regardless of the protocol used, so why not do it serverside?

Comment: if you don't want the warning you would need to modify at server. It's too late after browser sees the url

Comment: Thanks Charlie, thought that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be done server side for the browser not to throw an insecure connection warning. The file with the responsible code is `/library/core/functions.render.php`, which you can see [here](https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla/blob/1307a604c4990ad7e0a5c67d08a94de8709a98a9/library/core/functions.render.php#L807).

`$PhotoURL` is the variable that needs to be changed. Using the following makes sure all images are loaded over the `https:` protocol: `str_replace('http://', 'https://', $PhotoURL)`.

I usually don't mind global scope on smaller software but in something as big as Vanilla it's like finding a needle in a haystack.

I couldn't find any other fixes for Vanilla in particular so I hope this helps people.